# JBoss: Unable to acquire lock on Fqn

Tags: java, caching, jboss, jboss-cache

We have some production **JBoss 5.0.1.GA** servers and from time to time we got this error

> Caused by: org.jboss.cache.lock.TimeoutException: Unable to acquire lock on Fqn [/persistence.unit:unitName=z-eBF-ejb3Beans.jar#ebf-ejb3-beansUnit/ar/com/sdd/ebf/bo/do
>   cument/DocumentBean/ENTITY/ar.com.sdd.ebf.bo.document.DocumentBean#55420546] after [25000] milliseconds for requestor [GlobalTransaction::420001]! Lock held by [
>   GlobalTransaction::406079]

We have two or three JBoss instances per Linux server, but not in a cluster. Just separated JBoss instances, each one with it's independent configuration and database.

We've been dealing with it since we moved from JBoss 4 to JBoss 5, and we can't figure out how to solve the problem.

We just need some clues, or where in the documentation to look at.

Comment: What do you mean by *time to time*? Once per minute, hour, day?

Comment: I guess you are using MVCC as NodeLockingScheme?

Comment: Yes jeha, we're using MVCC
`<property name="nodeLockingScheme">MVCC</property>`
I don't fully understand what all of this means. Can I just remove the JBoss Cache from our instances ? We don't really use it, but we don't know if Hibernate or the JBoss is using it

Comment: Related: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/129143

Comment: Thanks @Dherik. I'm gonna take a look